# Consistent tab spacing in custom attribute table in QGIS Atlas

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, print-composer, atlas

I am trying to have consistent spacing between various columns using `'\t'` but it does not seem to work. I tried adding spaces manually but the output is not very pleasing as is evident from the image. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can achieve my goal of aligning the text in different columns with their column headings.

[image]

Comment: Try using non-true type font, e.g. Lucinda Console

Comment: Thanks @FelixIP- Using that font helped a bit but the areas were still not aligned. I tried to remove one '\t' in each subsequent row and then they aligned perfectly. I'm not sure why I had to do that though.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly add the attribute table to map composer via [image] **Add attribute table** wich create clean formatted table. You can than configure different headings, some appearance and styling.
See QGIS documentation: [The Attribute Table item](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/print_composer.html#the-attribute-table-item)

If you need to add formated text via [image] **Add new label**, you can also render table with HTML, checking *Render as HTML* checkbox or use [image] **Add HTML frame**. The code will be something like:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th width="250px">
            column 1
        </th>
        <th width="250px">
            column 2
        </th>
        <th width="250px">
            column 3
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="250px">
            some text
        </td>
        <td width="250px">
            some text
        </td>
        <td width="250px">
            some text
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For inserting values of attributes to HTML code in [Atlas generation](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/print_composer.html#atlas-generation) use code like this:

```html
<th width="250px">
    attribute_name
</th>
<td width="250px">
    [%"attribute_name"%]
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Oto, however I want the table to be transposed. The method you've mentioned doesn't work very well in my case.